# Octal to binary conversion confusion

Tags: c++, number-systems

I have a code in C++ which convert 2 digits octal number to binary number. For testing validity of the code I used several online conversion site like

[this](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/numbers/calculator/octal-to-binary/) and
[this](http://ncalculators.com/digital-computation/binary-octal-converter.htm)

When I enter 58 or 59 in as an octal value it says invalid octal values but when I enter 58 in my code it gives binary number as - 101000. Again for testing I enter 101000 as binary number in above website's calculator then they gives me result 50 as octal value.

I need some explanation why this is so.

Here is the C++ code -

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
void octobin(int);

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a;
    cout << "Enter a 2-digit octal number : ";
    cin>>a;
    octobin(a);
    getch();
}
void octobin(int oct)
{
    long bnum=0;
    int A[6];
    //Each octal digit is converted into 3 bits, 2 octal digits = 6 bits.
    int a1,a2,quo,rem;
    a2=oct/10;
    a1=oct-a2*10;
    for(int x=0;x<6;x++)
    {
        A[x]=0;
    }
    //Storing the remainders of the one's octal digit in the array.
    for (x=0;x<3;x++)
    {
        quo=a1/2;
        rem=a1%2;
        A[x]=rem;
        a1=quo;
    }
    //Storing the remainders of the ten's octal digit in the array.
    for(x=3;x<6;x++)
    {
        quo=a2/2;
        rem=a2%2;
        A[x]=rem;
        a2=quo;
    }
    //Obtaining the binary number from the remainders.
    for(x=x-1;x>=0;x--)
    {
        bnum*=10;
        bnum+=A[x];
    }
    cout << "The binary number for the octal number " << oct << " is " << bnum << "." << endl;
}
```

Comment: `void main` is not a valid signature for `main`. Use `int main`.

Comment: `clrscr` is not a standard C or C++ function.  Why do you need to clear the screen each time (it will erase the previous data that may be useful in solving problems)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octal numbers have digits that are all in the range `[0,7]`. Thus, `58` and `59` are *not* octal numbers, and your method should be expected to give erroneous results.

The reason that `58` evaluates to `101000` is because the first digit of the octal number expands to the first three digits of the binary number. `5 = 101_2`. Same story for the second part, but `8 = 1000_2`, so you only get the `000` part.

An alternate explanation is that `8 = 0 (mod 8)` (I am using the `=` sign for [congruency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) here), so both `8` and `0` will evaluate to `000` in binary using your code.

The best solution would be to do some input validation. For example, while converting you could check to make sure the digit is in the range `[0,7]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 58 or 59 as an input value. It's octal, for Christ's sake.

Valid digits are from 0 to 7 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

58 and 59 aren't valid octal values indeed ... the maximum digit you can use is yourbase-1 :

decimal => base = 10 => Digits from 0 t 9

hexadécimal => base = 16 => Digits from 0 to 15 (well, 0 to F)

Octal => base = 8 => Digits from 0 to 7

Answer (score 0):

If you're encoding a number in base 8, none of the octets can be 8 or greater. If you're going to do the code octet by octet, there needs to be a test to see whether the octet is 8 or 9, and to throw an error. Right now your code isn't checking this so the 8 and 9 are overflowing to 10.